# How do I create aggregates by a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried reading the [pandas groupby documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), but I can't follow it (I need more examples). I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

I want a new dataframe with two rows, `foo` and `bar`, with the summed values of C in one column, and the summed value of `C/D` in another column. Like this, for example:

```
A      C     C_over_D
'foo'  1.2   3.4
'bar'  2.3   5.4
```

I can just about get the summed value of C like this:

```
df = df.groupby('A')['C'].sum()
```

Although this gives me a data object back with no column name for C:

```
A
bar   -0.821788
foo   -6.006086
```

But how do I extend this to (a) return a proper dataframe with a column for C *(b) return the value of C over D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need [aggregation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) for your column `C` and for column `C/D` which you should create:

```
np.random.seed(632)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

df['C/D'] = df['C'] / df['D']

In [293]: df.groupby('A')['C', 'C/D'].agg(sum)
Out[293]:
            C       C/D
A
bar  0.060808 -8.173028
foo -1.461735 -0.058941
```

For flat dataframe you could also use `reset_index`:

```
In [294]: df.groupby('A')['C', 'C/D'].agg(sum).reset_index()
Out[294]:
     A         C       C/D
0  bar  0.060808 -8.173028
1  foo -1.461735 -0.058941
```